# how to get dataset value

Tags: jquery, dataset

```
<div id="story">
<p data-x="0">lorem ipsum...</p>
<p data-x="3">lorem ipsum...</p>
<p data-x="10">lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

js

```
$("#btnleft").click(function(){
    var part = 1;
    var a = $("#story > p").eq(part);
    var b = a.dataset["data-x"];
    console.log (b);
});
```

I expect `3` as a result, but console says:
`Cannot read property 'data-x' of undefined`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no property called `'dataset'` in a jquery object. You need to extract the data-attribute by changing

```
 var b = a.dataset["data-x"];
```

to

```
var b = a.data("x"); 

// or 

var b = a.attr("data-x");
```

Answer (score 4):

eq returns jQuery object. You need to use $.data() function.
For example:

```
$("#btnleft").click(function(){
    var part = 1;
    var $a = $("#story > p").eq(part);
    var b = $a.data('x');
    console.log(b);
});
```